# How can I identify the same request at each level of wcf extensibility points?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-extensions

**The main objective:** I want to correlate the informations calculated at each level of my wcf extensibility points.

**My Approach:** To do that, I need to identify the same request at each level of extensibility point, and merge informations related to the same request.

**The questions:**  Is there a way to identify the same request across different extensibility points?

Thanks for help